# Javax.ImageIO.IIOException for PNG image Data

Tags: java, android, tcp

I am implementing a server in java which recieves images from an android application. basically it is recieving image from android emulator but not from android device. This all process of recieving an image from android emulator or android device is done on localhost.

here is my code of the server.

```
public class Server {

private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static String message;
private static byte[] image;

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4000); // Server socket

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4000");
    }
    System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4000");

    while (true) {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
        DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        int count = inputFromClient.available();
        System.out.println(count);
        image = new byte[count];
        inputFromClient.readFully(image);
        final BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(image));
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File("image.jpg"));
    }
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1308)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1577)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)
at server.Server.main(Server.java:39)

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodePass(PNGImageReader.java:1092)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodeImage(PNGImageReader.java:1196)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1301)
... 4 more

Java Result: 1
```

I am getting an exception of javax.imageiio.exception in case of sending an image from android device but for android emulator it is working fine. Kindly help me out plz. Thank You.

Comment: post your exception please

Comment: @DavidJhons I have updated my post with exception as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is located in this line:

```
int count = inputFromClient.available();
```

It returns the number of bytes that are already received at that time. However there may be more bytes waiting to be transferred on the server side. 
Therefore the transmitted image is truncated/incomplete when you try to load it.

You have now two choices:

1. Before transferring the image data send an integer containing the length of the data
2. If only one image is transferred close the stream on client side after the image has been written. On server side you now have to read until you reach the end of the stream.